# Why can't I see birthdays on my Facebook home page?

Tags: facebook

I used to be able to see friends' birthdays in the right panel of my homepage. But now all I get is the minifeed and ads. And this isn't because none of my friends are celebrating today; If I click events I see that 3 friends were born on this day some years ago.

It appears I am not the only user (still) experiencing this issue. [Here's a not very helpful help thread at Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200302570741102).

Why did birthdays get buried?

> Update (6/21): Birthdays are back for me. This problem seems to have corrected itself.

Comment: It is showing up for me. Did you change any setting?

Comment: @hydra Settings are the same as always =(

Answer (score 1):

That's weird! You should be able to see your friends birthdays in the right hand side panel. No changes were made recently that would affect this - friends' birthdays are important to people on FB! If you don't mind, file a bug so the userops team can look into this. Or email me with a scrnshot and I'll pass it along.